# why is my button not appearing next to my <textarea> tag?

Tags: html, css

why isn't by button named "copy" appearing next to my second `textarea` tag and instead appearing under it even though im sorting elements with `display: flex;` in css? I have tried putting the `display: flex;`in the css for my second form tag but that does not work. Thank you for taking the time to read this, my code is below.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
    var output= document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
 }

 function idk() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("ascii");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.button {
    margin-top: none;
}

.txt {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: #4CAF50;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.ascii {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alphabetical.css">

</head>
<body>
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>        
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="ascii" id="output" type="text" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="idk()">
    </form>
    <script src="alphabetical.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: vertical-align: top; to button and text-area